# Proof Question using Proof By Contradiction, irrationality of $a + \sqrt[b]{5}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I answered this question but am not quite sure if i did what was correct. If anything is wrong please point it out, thanks.

Question:Prove that any number of the form $a + \sqrt[b]5$ is irrational, where $a,b$ are integers and $b \ne 0$

My Answer:

Proof by Contradiction:

Assume $a + \sqrt[b]5$ is rational:

Assume $p$/$q$ is in lowest terms where GCD($p$,$q$) = $1$ where $p$, $q$ are integers and $q \ne $0

$$\begin{align}
a + \sqrt[b]{5} &= {p \over q} & \\\
    \sqrt[b]{5} &= \frac pq - a \\
              5 &= \left(\frac pq - a\right)^b \\
              5 &= \frac{(p - qa)^b}{q^b}   & \text{(Multiplying q to be the denominator of the whole equation)} \\
           5q^b &= (p - qa)^b         &\text{(Isolating q and this shows }(p-qa)^b\text{ is a multiple of 5)}
\end{align}$$

Assuming $5c = p - qa$:

$$5q^b = 5^bc^b$$

How do i show q^b is a multiple of 5? Because if the question had a integer other than b then I could prove for odd and even numbers using (5p+1)^b and (5p+2)^b where b is an integer such as 1, 2, ... b then I can expand it and show there is a common divisor of 5 but I cannot do that in this case because I dont know what b is. The assumption to show this equation is rational if and only if b$\sqrt5$ is rational will work but I already knew that my problem is actually showing b$\sqrt5$ is rational.

Then,

$$5q^b = 5\left(5^{b-1}c^b\right) ~~~~\text{(which implies q is a multiple of 5)}$$

Since $q$ is a multiple of $5$:

$$\begin{align}
q &= 5x &\text 
p - 5xa &= 5c \\
p &= 5(xa + c)
\end{align}$$

This implies that both $p$ and $q$ are divisible by $5$. Which contradicts GCD($p$,$q$) = $1$ since $5$ is a greater common divisor than $1$. Thus the assumption of $a + \sqrt[b]5$ is rational is false.

Comment: first, assume that the gcd of p and q is 1, which you can always do...but make sure to note that explicitly.  Second,  are you talking about $b\cdot \sqrt 5$ or $b^{\sqrt 5}?$

Comment: I edited the confusing part sorry about that. Now check if it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: where you have $5q^b=5(5^{b-1}c^b)$,  that does not imply q is a multiple of 5...since you can cancel a 5 from each side, what you have left with is $q^b=5^{b-1}c^b$.  This would only mean q is a multiple of 5 IF $b-1\ge 1$,  but unfortunately $b-1$ can be 0

Comment: Thanks Alan I will look into it and try to fix it

Comment: So would there be a different or easier way to show q is divisible by 5?

Comment: Such as playing with 5q^b to multiply it with RHS

Comment: To make this easier, $a + \sqrt[b]5$ is irrational if and only if $\sqrt[b]5$ is irrational.

Comment: Hey Daniel I edited my work, take a look if you have time. But I am still stuck on showing q is a multiple of 5.

Comment: @geforce Consider carefully whether $a + \sqrt[1]5$ is rational.  It is important.  Then consider how that affects your attempt to prove that $q$ is a multiple of $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last paragraph is wrong:

> This implies that both p and q are multiples of 5 so there is a contradiction because the equation is irrational so there cannot be any common factors for it to be irrational.

It's like you've seen a proof of contradiction before, borrowed some words from it, and had no idea what the actual logic was.  Memorizing won't get you far in mathematics.  It looks like random incoherent rambling.

To correct your proof, first, your statement

> For some integer p,q where q is not zero

is incomplete.  You need to specify that $\frac pq$ is in lowest common terms, in other words that $\operatorname{GCD}(p,q) = 1$.

Second, your conclusion should be:

- Therefore $p$ and $q$ are both divisible by $5$
- This contradicts the assumption that $\operatorname{GCD}(p,q) = 1$
- Therefore the assumption that $a + \sqrt[b]5$ is rational must be false

Comment: I actually wrote this proof myself I just didn't understand how to conclude it. Also what does GCD?. Is it greatest common denominator?

Comment: I appreciate the help but the way you described my mistake of the conclusion isn't the most polite way.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction .  I wasn't trying to be mean, but it really does not seem like a language/grammar issue.  I suggest organizing your thoughts into multiple sentences instead of trying to make one long sentence.

Comment: Alan stated my line "5^qb=5(5^(b−1)c^b)" is not true when x=0 but in your response you did not mention it being wrong. So does that mean it works?

Comment: Ok thanks for the link and information I will definitely look into it.

Comment: Alan is correct.  Consider whether $a + \sqrt[1]5$ irrational.  I missed that you wrote $b \ne 0$ rather than $b > 1$ and he caught it.

Answer (score 1):

1. $b \in \mathbb{Z^+}\\ \sqrt[b]5=\dfrac{p}{q}, \operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1\\\implies 5=\dfrac{p^b}{q^b} \\ \implies 5q^b=p^b\\ \implies p \mid 5 \\\implies p=5 \\\implies q^b=5^{b-1}$

$b-1>0 \implies 5\mid q \implies q=5k \implies 5^b \cdot k^b=5^{b-1} \implies 5k^b=1$

$\therefore \not \exists p,q\mid \operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1 \land \sqrt[b]5=\dfrac{p}{q}$ ,$\forall b \in \mathbb{N}$ $\implies$ $\sqrt[b]5 \in \mathbb {R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \implies a+\sqrt[b]5 \in \mathbb {R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ , $\forall a \in \mathbb {Z}$

$b \in \mathbb{Z^-} \implies \exists t\in \mathbb {N} \mid b=-t \implies \sqrt[b]5=\sqrt[-t]5=\dfrac{1}{5^{\dfrac{1}{t}}}$

$\exists r,s \mid \operatorname{gcd}(r,s)=1, t \in\mathbb {N} \land \sqrt[-t]5=\dfrac{r}{s} \implies \sqrt[t]5 = \dfrac{s}{r}$ !!

Comment: So then what I did is right I just have to prove for b-1 > 0 correct? But b-1 can also be equal to 0 why did you not include that?

Comment: @geforce: I have included that. Please read the argument once more.

Comment: OK I see, u used if b is a member of negative integers and solved it that way

Comment: Double check $b=1 \implies \sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.  It is vacuously true, but what you should be concerned of is $\sqrt[1]{5} \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: @DanielV: Thanks for your suggestion. Removed it.

Comment: @geforce: $b \neq 1,-1$.

Comment: in case 2 why use R real numbers because it can be rational/irrational , negative or zero.. won't that not work for the case in every possible situation ?

Comment: Also the case won't work if b=1,-1?  Because of 1sqrt(5)?